# Atomic Operations in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a set of C++ functions:

```
funcB(){};
funcC(){};
funcA()
{
    funcB();
    funcC();
}
```

Now I want to make `funcA` atomic, ie `funcB` and `funcC` calls inside `funcA` should be executed atomically. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "executed atomically"? It sounds like you just want a `std::mutex`.

Comment: That's probably what he actually wants.

Comment: Maybe somebody ought to show him the proper syntax to use a `std::mutex`.  Maybe he doesn't know.  I wouldn't know how to use a mutex in some other languages.  The explanation should probably include the assumption that the entire program has to respect the mutex.  I.e. thread B can still call funcB and funcC even if thread A does so under a mutex, unless the programmer forbids it via design.

Comment: Why the downvote on this question? It seems a perfectly reasonable thing to ask.

Answer (score 11):

One way you can accomplish this is to use the new (C++11) features `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard`.

For each protected resource, you instantiate a single global `std::mutex`; each thread then locks that mutex, as it requires, by the creation of a `std::lock_guard`:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

// A single mutex, shared by all threads. It is initialized
// into the "unlocked" state
std::mutex m;

void funcB() {
  std::cout << "Hello ";
}
void funcC() {
  std::cout << "World." << std::endl;
}
void funcA(int i) {

  // The creation of lock_guard locks the mutex
  // for the lifetime of the lock_guard
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);

  // Now only a single thread can run this code
  std::cout << i << ": ";
  funcB();
  funcC();

  // As we exit this scope, the lock_guard is destroyed, 
  // the mutex is unlocked, and another thread is allowed to run
}

int main () {
  std::vector<std::thread> vt;

  // Create and launch a bunch of threads
  for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
    vt.push_back(std::thread(funcA, i));

  // Wait for all of them to complete
  for(auto& t : vt)
    t.join();
}
```

Notes:

- In your example some code unrelated to `funcA` could invoke either `funcB` or `funcC` without honoring the lock that `funcA` set.
- Depending upon how your program is structured, you may want to manage the lifetime of the mutex differently. As an example, it might want to be a class member of the class that includes `funcA`.

Answer (score 6):

In general, NO. Atomic operations are very precisely defined. What you want is a semaphore or a mutex.

Comment: Please note that while this answer is strictly speaking correct, Robᵩ's answer is more useful to user744829.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GCC 4.7 than you can use the new **Transactional Memory** feature to do the following:

Transactional memory is intended to make programming with threads simpler, in particular synchronizing access to data shared between several threads using transactions. As with databases, a transaction is a unit of work that either completes in its entirety or has no effect at all (i.e., transactions execute atomically). Further, transactions are isolated from each other such that each transaction sees a consistent view of memory.

Currently, transactions are only supported in C++ and C in the form of transaction statements, transaction expressions, and function transactions. In the following example, both a and b will be read and the difference will be written to c, all atomically and isolated from other transactions:

```
__transaction_atomic { c = a - b; }
```

Therefore, another thread can use the following code to concurrently update b without ever causing c to hold a negative value (and without having to use other synchronization constructs such as locks or C++11 atomics):

```
__transaction_atomic { if (a > b) b++; }
```

The precise semantics of transactions are defined in terms of the C++11/C1X memory model (see below for a link to the specification). Roughly, transactions provide synchronization guarantees that are similar to what would be guaranteed when using a single global lock as a guard for all transactions. Note that like other synchronization constructs in C/C++, transactions rely on a data-race-free program (e.g., a nontransactional write that is concurrent with a transactional read to the same memory location is a data race).

More info: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/TransactionalMemory